# Created a Google Apps script to retrieve my events for the current day and send an email if there's a recording

Tags: google-apps-script

Not ideal, but i wanted something quick to

1. scroll through current day events in my calendar
2. Find the event with a specific title i.e "Test"
3. Find if the event has a recording attached to the meeting
4. Send an email if the recording is attached to the meeting called "Test.

This is what I have so far,

```
function sendEmailIfVideoAttached() {
  // Set the email recipient
  var recipient = "test@example.com";

  // Get today's calendar events
  var today = new Date();
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEventsForDay(today);

  // Find the event titled "Test" and check if it has a video attachment
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    if (event.getTitle() == "Test") {
      var attachments = event.getAttachments();
      for (var j = 0; j < attachments.length; j++) {
        var attachment = attachments[j];
        if (attachment.getContentType().startsWith("video/")) {
          // If there's a video attachment, send an email to the recipient
          MailApp.sendEmail({
            to: recipient,
            subject: "Test event has a video attachment",
            body: "The Test event on " + today.toLocaleDateString() + " has a video attachment.",
          });
          return; // Stop looking for more events
        }
      }
      // If the event doesn't have an attachment with a video content type, check the fileId
      var attachmentIds = event.getAttachmentIds();
      for (var k = 0; k < attachmentIds.length; k++) {
        var fileId = attachmentIds[k];
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
        var fileMimeType = file.getMimeType();
        if (fileMimeType.startsWith("video/")) {
          // If there's a video file attachment, send an email to the recipient
          MailApp.sendEmail({
            to: recipient,
            subject: "Test event has a video attachment",
            body: "The Test event on " + today.toLocaleDateString() + " has a video attachment.",
          });
          return; // Stop
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the above code isn't working and not giving me what I want it to unfortunately. What's wrong with it?

An email with the recording from the event that the script picked up from the title.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is the getAttachments() method. Such a method does not exist in the CalendarEvent class.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event

Try the below code. I've tested it and it worked on my end. Just make sure you have enabled the V3 of Calendar API Advanced service in your script editor.

```
function sendEmailIfVideoAttached() {
  var calendarId = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getId();
  var today = new Date();
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEventsForDay(today);
  var recipient = 'test@example.com';

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    if (events[i].getTitle() == "Test") {
      var eventId = events[i].getId();
      eventId = eventId.substring(0, eventId.indexOf("@google.com"));
      var res = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId, { fields: "attachments/fileId" });
      if (res.attachments) {
        var fileIds = res.attachments.map(function (e) { return e.fileId });
        // Added below code in try block because it will throw an exception if the user running the function does not have access to the attachment.
        try {
          var fileMimeType = DriveApp.getFileById(fileIds[0]).getMimeType();
          if (fileMimeType.startsWith("video/")) {
            // If there's a video file attachment, send an email to the recipient
            MailApp.sendEmail({
              to: recipient,
              subject: "Test event has a video attachment",
              body: "The Test event on " + today.toLocaleDateString() + " has a video attachment.",
            });
            return; // Stop
          }
        }
        catch (e) {
          console.error(e.message);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to me. I updated the code and it executes. I know that the line you said getattachments() doesn't work and I looked at your suggestions from the link you said but I've spend 3 days on this and with those suggestions, I do apologize, I wouldn't know how to integrate it. I tried and it executed.

Comment: I updated the code but have been playing with it. Google apps script isn't really my strong suit :( agh i suck

Comment: Updated the answer with entire code. Please try it now.